# How to get the length of the I/O queues which access disks in Linux kernel

Tags: io, linux-kernel

How to get the length of the I/O queue (all I/O access disks) in Linux kernel?
Is there a function or a variable which can get the length?

Comment: Length of I/O?  Do you mean the amount of time spent waiting for I/O?  Are you looking for the latency of a specific I/O request, or something like a system-wide average?

Comment: length of I/O queues means counts of I/O queues including waiting for I/O and being executing I/O. I have to get the realtime I/O length which we can use it.

Comment: @user824675 The "queue" word seems quite important then. Shame you forgot to put it in the title **or** the question body. Next time, you could make it a lot easier for people to answer your question if you actually put all the relevant information in there. "length of the I/O" isn't quite the same thing as "length of the I/O queue". If you mean the latter, why not *say* it?

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistakes. Would you please tell me the method to get the length of the I/O queue? I thought a method that using jprobe to get the length but this method slowing down the performance of the computer. Thank you very much.